# Generators of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show the following:

Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $5$ and $7$.

I think that the solution has to do with relative prime numbers but I don't know where to start.

Comment: $ 15 - 14 = 1 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is a quite useful theorem called [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: I understand that the gcd is 1. But how do i use that to show that all integers is generated by 5 and 7.

Comment: Because $5$ and $7$ therefore "generate" $1$. And once you can generate $1$...

Comment: Once we generate 1 by claiming it as the gcd, we can then use 1 as a generator for Z since all integers are generated by multiples of 1?

Comment: @Student Yup. That's the most important part of Bézout's identity: sure you can generate the GCD, but crucially, you can therefore generate any multiple of the GCD - and *nothing else*.

Comment: Is it safe to say that since 5 and 7 generate 1, and 1 generates Z, then 5 and 7 generate Z. Am I understanding this correctly or do I need to include anything more in the proof?

Comment: @Student That's probably enough, but you could use Bézout's identity to give an explicit formula to generate $n\in\Bbb Z$ from $5$ and $7$.